# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt6'

Tags: python, macos, pyqt6, modulenotfounderror

After creating a virtual environment for Python on my mac and installing PyQt6, when I type:
from Pyqt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QVboxLayout in IDLE it works with no error but when I try to do so from VSCode, I get the error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt6'.  The respective sys.paths from IDLE is:

```
['', '/Users/awegele/Documents', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python312.zip', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/lib-dynload', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages']
```

while in VSCode it is:

```
['/Users/awegele/Documents/Personal Python/Personal', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python312.zip', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/lib-dynload', '/Users/awegele/Documents/Personal Python/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages']
```

While I was very familiar with Path statements in Windows, I have never really become comfortable with paths on the Mac which is perhaps part of my problem.  Please help

I expected it to work in IDLE and VSCode

Comment: From your `sys.path`, it seems you didn't install `PyQt6` in virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely need to enable the virtual environment in VS code by clicking on the following button and selecting the venv you just created.
[image]

Comment: Thank you but that did not solve the problem.

Comment: Are you sure that you installed PyQt6 into the virtual environment? It should not be under `'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages'`, but instead under `'/Users/awegele/Documents/Personal Python/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages'`. You might have to activate the venv in your command line and install pyqt6 if that is not the case.

Comment: I'm not sure I installed PyQt6 into the virtual environment.  When I "activate" the virtual environment in VSCode by clicking on the right lower corner where it says 3.12.1('.venv':venv) then try to install pyqt6 in the terminal window in VScode using pip install pyqt6 I get a message saying: Requirement already satisfied: pyqt6 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages (6.6.1) plus another line that won't fit in the comment window

Comment: But when I try  "from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QvBoxLayout" in a script, the PyQt6.QtWidgets is not recognized

Comment: The problem is that selecting the virtual environment in VS Code won't automatically enable it in the integrated terminal. You still will have to activate it separately here, for example using `source tutorial-env/bin/activate`. See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html

Comment: I was able to activate my virtual environment .venv then installed pyqt6.  That resolved the import reference.  Then I created a file Test.ui with QtDesigner (which got installed) some time ago when I installed PyQt5 but not in a virtual environment.  But now when I try to run the code (see next comment)

Comment: import typing
from PyQt6 import QtCore
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt6.uic import loadUi
import sys

class MainUI(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle = "My Main Window"
        self.setGeometry(200,200, 300, 300)
        loadUi('Test.ui', self)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = MainUI()
    ui.show()
    app.exec()  I get an error (see next comment)

Comment: File "/Users/awegele/Documents/Personal Python/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/PyQt6/uic/properties.py", line 432, in setProperties
    getattr(widget, 'set%s%s' % (ascii_upper(prop_name[0]), prop_name[1:]))(prop_value) (There were several more lines in the error message but I can't get it all in the comment field)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: I think your code contains errors. It should be setWindowTitle("My Main Window") and __init__(self) and if __name__ == '__main__'. For simpler errors I can recommend asking ChatGPT.